# How to extract date from a string in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, date, string-parsing

I have two Strings. The first is like this one:

```
{"userId":"554555454-45454-54545","start":"20141114T172252.466z","end":"20141228T172252.466z","accounts":[{"date":"20141117T172252.466z","tel":"0049999999999","dec":"a dec","user":"auser"},{"date":"20141118T172252.466z","tel":"004888888888","dec":"another dec","user":"anotheruser"}]}
```

the second one has the same dates but in a different format. Instead of

> 20141117T172252.466z

it shows

> 2014-11-14,17:22:52

I'm trying to extract the dates of the first String and assert that are the same with the dates from the second String. I've tried it with regular expressions but I'm getting an error Illegal repetition. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat from java:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
val s1 = "{\"userId\":\"554555454-45454-54545\",\"start\":\"20141114T172252.466z\"}"
val s2 = "{\"userId\":\"554555454-45454-54545\",\"start\":\"2014-11-14,17:22:52\"}"
val i1 = s1.indexOf("start")
val i2 = s2.indexOf("start")
val str1 = s1.replace("T", "_").substring(i1+8, i1+ 23)
val str2 = s2.substring(i2+8, i2+27)
val date1: Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss").parse(str1)
val date2: Date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd,hh:mm:ss").parse(str2)
val result = date1==date2
```

Comment: I imagine that I can use it but my first issue is how to extract the dated of these two Strings. Thank you very much rtruszk

Comment: It's really good but the second string is very different from the first one. The date (2014-11-14,17:22:52) has not any tag like start as there is in the first one. If I could change the date1 from Fri Nov 14 22:57:01 GMT 2014 to 2014-11-14,22:57:01 I would be able to assert that exists in the second String just by using contains! An extra issue is that it's not only one date in the Strings there are 6 different start that I have to check that are actually the same. Sorry, If I didn't describe it correctly from the beginning. Thank you very much rtruszk

Comment: With your solution I'm able to get Fri Nov 14 22:57:01 GMT 2014 from the first String. If I convert this to 2014-11-14,22:57:01 I'll be able to assert that the second String has this date by using just the contains. So, there is no need to do anything in the second String. The next step is to repeat this for all the dates because there are six, not just one.